# Making use of FRP to handle object manipulation and store

Tags: javascript, json, object, reactjs, frp

I am working on a project making use of react and am wanting to implement a form of FRP to handle events when a given object is altered in any given form.

I've done some research into Bacon.js and RX.js and am still a bit uncertain as to how I would go about making the full use of one of these libraries to trigger functions on an objects alteration(adding/removing/editing object elements) as well implementing a type of datastore with them.

How would the above be attained using FRP or namely one of the above mentioned libraries and furthermore, is this the type of use I should be looking at FRP for?

Comment: It sounds like you don't necessarily need to use those libraries to implement the kind of functionality that you're looking for. Look into observables. By making your data observable, you can trigger a bunch of subscribers that will 'react' to any changes that take place.

Comment: I did see that, I just want to get into that programming style and noticed that both libs have built in support for such features like observables and reactions.

Comment: I can highly recommend reading this: https://github.com/Day8/re-frame. It's written up for a Clojurescript React library, but it describes the basic pattern very well. I'm combining the ideas presented there with Bacon.js and Baobab and it works really well.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Mobservable](http://mweststrate.github.io/mobservable/) it integrates with React really well in my opinion. Also [here's a comparison](https://github.com/mweststrate/mobservable/issues/18) of FRP styles, and how Mobservable is different/better.